# Continuity of 1/x/x

Tags: continuity

We know that if $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are continuous in a domain then $f(x)/g(x)$ is continuous in the domain except for those elements in the domain for which $g(x) = 0$. If I take two functions $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = 1/x$, then $f(x)$ is continuous for all $R$ and $g(x)$ is continuous for $R-\{0\}$ but if I take $f(x)/g(x)$ which is $x/1/x$ or $x^2$ then it is continuous for all $R$ even when $0$ was not in the domain of $g(x)$. Is this correct?

Comment: Not exactly because $\frac{x}{\frac{1}{x}} = x^2$ only when $x \neq 0$, so at $x=0$, $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ is undefined

Comment: To elaborate, $f(x)/g(x)$ is undefined at $0$ but has a removable discontinuity. So if it *were* defined at $0$, the discontinuity could be removed.

Answer (score 3):

> **A function is not just defined by its mapping rule but also by the domain and codomain!**

As mentioned in the comments, you have to check the domain carefully. If you have two functions $f:D\to \mathbb R$ and $g:E\to\mathbb R$ then $h:=\frac{f}{g}$ is defined on
$$
\{x\in D\cap E~:~g(x)\neq 0\}.
$$
In your case $D=\mathbb R$ and $E=\mathbb R\setminus \{0\}$. Because $g(x)\neq 0$ holds for all $x\in E$, you get $D\cap E=E$ as your domain of the quotient $h$. Further $h$ is continuous at each point of $E$ as composition of continuous functions.

Nevertheless, there are a lot of examples, where the quotient $h$ can be continuously extended to a larger domain $F\supset E$. In your case, you can extend $h$ continuously to whole $\mathbb R$. But keep in mind, that the extension is formally not the same as the quotient $h$.